# How to target this HTML in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style Vanilla Forums and I just can't seem to figure out to select this class `<li class="Item Announcement"></li>` so that I can style it.

I don't know why it's being so difficult. Why would this not work?

```
.Item Announcement {
background-color: #FFF;
{
```

Comment: right now you have 2 classes there, Item and Announcement.

Comment: @JohnB: More specifically, the `li` element has two classes.  The CSS directive is referring to `Announcement` _elements_ (which don't exist) inside of any elements with the class `Item`.  So it would (_should_, I imagine this is undefined) apply the style to something like this: `<li class="Item"><Announcement /></li>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
li.Item.Announcement {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

That list item has two classes applied to it (Item and Announcement). So to target that with CSS, you need to prefix each class with a period and then remove the spaces. Leaving the spaces in the CSS selector would apply it to a descendant element that had the class.

Quick **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vxmdQ/)**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with spaces, its is no longer one selector but two, so you need to select using multiple class selector.

```
.Item.Announcement {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your class name has a space in it. You probably meant for it to be a single class name - so change it to `class="ItemAnnouncement"` and `.ItemAnnouncement { ...`  and everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `<li class="Item Announcement"></li>` is actually two classes. Classes cannot have spaces in their names. You can select this element with either li, .Item, .Announcement, or a combination of all three.

To make sure that you are selecting that exact element, your code should look something like this:

```
li.Item.Announcement {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the space you have in your class name adds two distinct classes in your html element, `.Item` & `.Announcement`. You should consider naming your class itemAnnouncement, or if you're not a camel case fan, item-announcement.

If on the other hand you meant to have different classes you can style the one that suits you best, i.e.

```
.Item {background-color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

spaces in class names and id are not allowed, so if you Put a space you are actually writing 2 class names for that item.